# XSD: Enumeration can contain more than one attribute?

Tags: xsd

Typically we define an enumeration in this way:

```
<xsd:enumeration value="World"/>
```

Can another attribute be added besides "value"? For example:

```
<xsd:enumeration value="World" another="something" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xsd:enumeration` element [doesn’t allow any attributes other than `value` and `id`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dc-enumeration).

It’s not clear from the question what you’re trying to do, but you know you can specify multiple `xsd:enumeration` elements, right? Isn’t that exactly what the element is for? So you can do this:

```xml
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:enumeration value="World"/>
  <xsd:enumeration value="something"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```